# How can I right click to select a node in a treeview control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, treeview

Why I right click on a node in my treeview the focus moves to this node and then immediately back to the previously selected node. Is there some way that I can allow the right click to select the node?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's because the highlight color performs *two* duties, it shows the selected node *and* shows the focused node.  If you don't do anything with the right-click event then it jumps back to the selected node.  The workaround is to select the node:

```
    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
    }
```

Plus anything else you want to do, usually displaying a context menu.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies I jumped the gun slightly I found how to do this as follows:

```
    Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            TreeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node
        End If
    End Sub
```

Shouldn't the control do this as standard though?